# How do I program a 2D array of random numbers so it follows a certain rules in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a table of propabilities which follows a rule that:
Starting from a top row the propability is the highest in first column and all consecutive propabilities in the row need to decrese.
For the second row the propability in the first colum is lower than in the second column and then it decreses again.
For the third row the highest is in the third place. And so on ...

Additionally sum of all values in each row needs to be 1.

I have already solved the normalization criterion:

1. Generate random nums
2. Find their sum
3. Devide each by the sum

But i don´t know how to do the other one.
I thought about generating values and inserting them diagonoally and each time i switch to next diagonall I change the range from which I choose random nums but I feel like there is a better solution.

If someone can just push me into the right direction would help alot.

Here is what i have:

```
import numpy as np
import random as rand


class DataGen:
    def __init__(self, processDuration, states, actions):
        self.processDuration = processDuration
        self.states = states
        self.actions = actions

        self.propabilityTable = np.empty(len(self.states), dtype=np.ndarray)
        self.CreateTable()
        self.RandomDataGen()

    def CreateTable(self):
        for i in range(len(states)):
            self.propabilityTable[i] = np.zeros((len(self.actions), len(self.states)))


    def RandomDataGen(self):
        for i in range(len(states)):
            for j in range(len(actions)):
                sum = 0
                for k in range(len(states)):
                    randNum = rand.random()
                    sum += randNum
                    self.propabilityTable[i][j][k] = randNum
                for k in range(len(states)):
                    self.propabilityTable[i][j][k] = self.propabilityTable[i][j][k]/sum
                # testSum = 0 
                # for k in range(len(states)):
                #     testSum += self.propabilityTable[i][j][k]
                #     print(testSum)


states = np.array([0, 1])
actions = np.array([10, 20, 30])
generator = DataGen(2, states, actions)
print(generator.propabilityTable)
```

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In particular, "How do I implement this feature" is discussed as being off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way to do it for a matrix of 4x5. The main idea is to use `sort` and then `roll`:

```
a = np.random.rand(20).reshape(4, 5)
a = a / a.sum(axis=0)
a.sort(axis=0)
a = a[::-1]
for i in range(5):
    a[:,i] = np.roll(a[:,i], i)
a.transpose()
```

The output is:

```
array([[0.41419359, 0.36678763, 0.16340826, 0.05561052],
       [0.08571914, 0.43379335, 0.31048916, 0.16999835],
       [0.25731826, 0.18396195, 0.28694531, 0.27177448],
       [0.28115312, 0.25913407, 0.05177595, 0.40793686],
       [0.32542887, 0.29564742, 0.27444447, 0.10447924]])
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i need! Thank you!